# Confusion regarding logic in paper, "A NOTE ON THE INVERSION OF POWER SERIES," published in the AMS journal

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inverse

I was reading ["A NOTE ON THE INVERSION OF POWER SERIES"](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1947-02-020/S0025-5718-1947-0022717-X/S0025-5718-1947-0022717-X.pdf) and was able to follow the paper's reasoning until the bottom of the second page, where it states:

> in fact we can calculate the power series $y^n$ for any real $n$ by making use of the binomial expansion $y^n=[a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_mx^m+\cdots]^n\\a_0^n\left[1+v\right]^n=a_0^n\left[1+nv+\cdots+\binom{n}{r}v^r+\cdots\right].$

I understand that he simply substituted for y in the first equation and then expanded using the binomial theorem in the second equation. What I do not understand is how the two equations are related. I assumed it would be explained later, so I continued to read, and it was relatively explained.

> Now we construct a table as in figure 2 for the function v. Above the top row, insert the numbers $\binom{n}{r}$ corresponding to the r-th column. Then the coefficient of $x^m$ in $y^n$ is $a_0^n\left[1+w_{m,n}\right]$ where $w_{m,n}=\sum\binom{n}{r}a_{m,r}$ is the accumulated product of the terms in the m-th row with the corresponding numbers $\binom{n}{r}$. Note that each sum is a finite sum because v has no constant term and therefore $a_{m,r}=0$ for $r>m$.

What I still do not understand is how and why that is true in regards to the coefficient of $x^m$. I would greatly appreciate any help in deducing the steps to derive the author's conclusion.

Comment: $y = f(x)$ where $f(x) = \sum_m a_m x^m$ ? and the target is to find a locally analytic function $g(y) = \sum_k b_k y^k $ such that $g(f(x)) = \sum_k b_k f(x)^k = \sum_k b_k ( \sum_m a_m x^m)^k = x$ for $|x| < \delta$

Comment: When you cite a journal paper, you should include the author name(s), and also the year/issue of the journal. On the other hand, there is absolutely no need to SHOUT the title of the paper.

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not sure if your response is a question of confirmation or if you just accidentally typed a question mark, but if it is, then I believe so.

Comment: @Rremmuoo : I just checked, this is what the paper is about : the problem of finding the coefficients of a power series for $g(y) = f^{-1}(y)$ , hence the equation is $g(f(x)) = f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that is a more accurate description. Do you have any insight specifically towards my original question above?